# Reply posting to discussion board using REST API

Tags: sharepoint

We are trying to give a reply to the existing topic discussion using the REST API in Microsoft SharePoint.

Below are request details.

```
URL:https://[TenantName].sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('dicussion board')/Items

Headers: Authorization:Bearer XXXX
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose
accept:application/json;odata=verbose

RequestBody:
{
    "Body": "<p>Test message using api</p>",
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.dicussion_x0020_boardListItem"
    },
    "ParentItemID":10,
   "ContentTypeId": "0x0000EE0020063889D45FD823B4A8455444117056EE3"
}
```

But this is creating a new topic in Sharepoint.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One single call can not do this based on my testing.

[the script](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/c5327ddbb1ceede884c14e35bb21117e) works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeJson(options) {
        var headers = options.headers || {};
        var method = options.method || "GET";
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        if (options.method == "POST") {
            headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
        }

        var ajaxOptions =
        {
            url: options.url,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: headers
        };
        if ("data" in options) {
            ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
        }

        return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }


    function createListItem(webUrl, listTitle, payload) {
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
        return executeJson({
            "url": url,
            "method": 'POST',
            "data": payload
        });
    }

    function moveListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, folderUrl) {
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")?$select=FileDirRef,FileRef";
        return executeJson({
            "url": url
        })
            .then(function (result) {
                var fileUrl = result.d.FileRef;
                var fileDirRef = result.d.FileDirRef;
                var moveFileUrl = fileUrl.replace(fileDirRef, folderUrl);
                var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + moveFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
                return executeJson({
                    "url": url,
                    "method": 'POST'
                });
            });
    }


    function getParentTopic(webUrl, listTitle, itemId) {
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")/Folder";
        return executeJson({
            "url": url,
        });
    }


    function createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl, listTitle, messagePayload) {
        var topicUrl = null;
        return getParentTopic(webUrl, listTitle, messagePayload.ParentItemID)
            .then(function (result) {
                topicUrl = result.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
                return createListItem(webUrl, listTitle, messagePayload);
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                var itemId = result.d.Id;
                return moveListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, topicUrl);
            });
    }


    var listTitle = "Dicussion Board";
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var messagePayload = {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.Dicussion_x0020_BoardListItem" },  //set DiscussionBoard entity type name
        'Body': "Test message using api",  //message Body
        'FileSystemObjectType': 0, //setto 0 to make sure Mesage Item
        'ContentTypeId': '0x0107001F110388B0388441BE3F004885E844F9', //set Message content type
        'ParentItemID': 1  //set Discussion (topic) Id
    };

    function CreateReply() {
        createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl, listTitle, messagePayload)
            .done(function (item) {
                console.log('Message(reply) has been sent');
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: While this appears to work (the reply shows up in the discussion thread of the parent post) it does not set the `ParentItemID` property on the reply, it remains `null` which breaks some of the features of discussions. See this article: [REST api support for discussion list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d4de96cc-53eb-4579-a7d4-97e575b08620/rest-api-support-for-new-discussion-list-in-community-site-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)